# Execute three commands in single command line in Linux

Tags: linux

How can I execute three commands on one command line in Linux?  I tried the below:

`sudo -u oracle -i ; cd /lo2/ram/daska; ./script.sh`

When I execute this only the `sudo` command is executing.

Please advise me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After executing `sudo` there's a new shell and the rest of "commands" are not part of it but part of the parent shell. You can do:

```
 sudo -u oracle -i bash -c "cd /lo2/ram/daska && ./script.sh"
```

Or directly,

```
 sudo -u oracle -i /lo2/ram/daska/script.sh
```

Comment: The latter depending on if the script needs this particular working directory or not...

Answer (score 4):

Use && separator

```
sudo -u oracle -i && cd /lo2/ram/daska && ./script.sh
```

Comment: just bear in mind that when using `&&` if any command in the chain fails, the rest won't be executed

Comment: Nope, this is not working I've tried with semicolon and && symbols ,its executing only first command .. please check again

Comment: If all commands succeed, then replacing `;` with `&&` makes no difference. In any case, this is not the issue and doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use semicolon to seperate your command

```
sudo -u oracle -i ; cd /lo2/ram/daska ; ./script.sh
```

The difference between using && and semicolon is that if you want to execute each command only if the previous one succeeds, then you can use the && operator. However if you want to execute commands, irrespective of previous one executes or not, you can use semicolon (;) to separate the commands.

Comment: Nope, this is not working I've tried with semicolon and && symbols ,its executing only first command .. please check again

Comment: @Ramdas:- Did you see the answer given by glglgl `sudo -u oracle sh -c 'cd /lo2/ram/daska; ./script.sh'`

Comment: Yes, but the oracle profile not getting there when i using the above command with -i .. i'm getting errors failing sqlplus command not found, When i execute the command manually its working fine

Answer (score 3):

I'll just add to Piperoman's and Rahul's answers that with `&&` the later command is only executed if the first succeeds and with `;` following command is always executed.

So

`sudo -u oracle -i ; cd /lo2/ram/daska ; ./script.sh`

if you don't care whether everything in the chain executes, and

`sudo -u oracle -i && cd /lo2/ram/daska && ./script.sh`

if you do.

Answer (score 3):

If you do

```
sudo -u oracle -i ; cd /lo2/ram/daska; ./script.sh
```

you tell that a login shell running under user `oracle` should be started. That happens, and the other commands are executed after you leave this shell.

This is probably not what you want.

I see the following option:

```
sudo -u oracle sh -c 'cd /lo2/ram/daska; ./script.sh'
```

which in principle is mentioned in sudo's man page.